# vuejs firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

[image]

I am trying to check if a user has logged in using `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()`. When I run the code, the application does not load/render any pages.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the user, as in the following sample from the official documentation:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

The listener itself is for detecting changes; you define the logged in/logged out behavior from within, according to the `user` object.

When there is no user, `user` will be null, so your signed-out case will happen;

when there is a user, the object will be truthy, triggering the signed in case, with a lot of properties on it, like `user.email` etc -- see the docs for more.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Answer (score 0):

On the application startup, firebase state not changes.

Try use:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser
```

To get the user authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

**solve all problems for you**

```
let app;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
console.log("user", user);
 if (!app) {
  app = new Vue({
   router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
  }
});
```